# How to use where conditional in with Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I do request using query:

```
return Baber::where(function ($query) use ($request) {

    // HERE CONDITION WHERE FOR USER TABLE

})->with("user")->orderBy('id', 'desc')->get();
```

How can I use `where()` inside query, that it will be comparabled with `user` table in `with("user")`?

I mean the following:

```
return Baber::where(function ($query) use ($request) {

        $query->where('user.created_at', $request->date);

    })->with("user")->orderBy('id', 'desc')->get();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's known as [constraining eager loads](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads).

```
Baber::with(['user' => function ($query) use ($request) {
    $query->where('user.created_at', '=', $request->date);
}])
->orderBy('id', 'desc')
->get();
```

Comment: While OP hinted 'with', `->whereHas()` might be the correct method if the intention is to 'get all baber(?), only if it has user created at `$request->date`. Constrained eager loads means 'get all baber, and also load related user, only if user is created at ...'. So there might be two possible distinct solution here.